# Why some apache server's htaccess not detect https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I often need to make redirects from https to http (or http to https), but not in all servers with apache works this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO} ^https$ [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

Whats rules also may helping to detect is url is https?

Comment: That depends if Apache is directly getting requests or if there is any proxy in the middle.

Comment: how to detect https if it use proxy?

Comment: Try this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my hosting works only this constant:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTPS']
```